# Route Public IP with GRE Tunnel with BGP/BIRD from a VPS to my Cisco at Home

Tags: networking, routing, bgp

I want to learn how to do this. I Will try to explain as better.
- First: I own a IP Block from RIPE
- Second: I have vultr.com VPS service and they are announcing my /24 and I can get the public IPs on the VPS with BIRD and dummy* interfaces.

- Third: I have a GRE tunnel stablished between one VPS and my home Cisco Router.

**WHAT I WANT?**
I want to set one the public IPs on my home, for come out to internet with one of my IPs. I think I need BGP over the GRE Tunnel, but I can't get it to work.

¿Is there any help with that?

Thanks in advance.

==============================================

## SCHEMA

VULTR VPS          ==================         CISCO

GRE: 1.1.1.1/24                               GRE: 1.1.1.2/24

Public: 2.2.2.1/24                            Public: ¿?¿?¿?¿?¿

On VULTR VPS i have announced the 2.2.2.1 and 2.2.2.5 so 2.2.2.1 are reachable on dummy interface and 2.2.2.5 are not yet reachable but are announced to internet.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need BGP between VPS and Cisco router. The static route is enough. That is example step algo, what you can do:

- On the VULTR VPS create the static route. Because you already announce the `2.2.2.5` address, you don't need other routing changes on this host. In the linux you can use this command:

`ip route add 2.2.2.5 via 1.1.1.2 dev <greiface>`

- On the cisco router you create the loopback interface and assign the `2.2.2.5` address on it. It's optinal step if you want use this public ip on the cisco router itself. Other way is usage of the NAT pool without the additional loopback interface itself.
- Setup the NAT on the cisco router to use the public ip as source address of outgoing packets.
- Create the route-map to route selected packets with your public ip through the GRE tunnel.

Comment: Is not working. I can reach the Cisco Loopback address from the VPS but not from internet. BIRD daemon is announcing gre1 interface but the gre1 dont have the public ip. Maybe the error is here? Already activated ip forward.